# Curly Braces: adding half-spaces around each brace

Tags: spacing, punctuation

When I use the commands `\{` and `\}`,  the braces rendered are "too tight" or hug too closely to the text and math that lies between them. I would like to redefine `\{` to `\{\,`, and `\}` to `\,\}` , but I'm not sure how to do this with delimiters.

Comment: have you already checked out the [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype) package? EDIT I suggest you see section 5 of the manual, which discusses the `\SetExtraKerning` command allowing you to adjust the spaces before and after individual characters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Answer (score 8):

A low tech solution would be to define a new command, such as:

`\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\{\,#1\,\}}`

Here's a MWE with picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
   \newcommand{\Set}[1]{\{\,#1\,\}}
\begin{document}
   \{a, b\} vs \Set{a, b} 

   $\{a, b\}$ vs $\Set{a, b}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from the question whether it was only to be used only in math mode: "the text ... that lies between" made me think it wasn't.  But you're right: the first definition `$\{\,#1\,\}$` is asking for trouble.  I'll amend the answer.

Comment: It's not “low tech” at all. `;-)`

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work for me, and curiously I had no compile error... nothing seemed to have happened.

Comment: @Peter: It's hard to say why it wouldn't have worked, without seeing some code.  I've added some to my answer.  Hopefully, that'll help.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. (I was doing something silly.) But is there a low tech way to "renewcommand" the braces themselves? Unfortunately I have been using `\{` and `\}` a lot, and I don't want to go back and change everything to `\Set`

Comment: Check out Heiko's answer below.  Alternatively, just do a two search-and-replace's: `\{` → `\Set{` and `\}` → `}`.

Answer (score 5):

Additional spaces (e,g,`\,`) can be added by redefining `\{` and `\}`. But it will not work for `\}`, it breaks `\right`, because the space would be inserted between `\right` and the delimiter. Therefore the example redefines `\right` to look for a following `\}` to insert the space at the right place before the original `\right`. The example also assumes that the spaces are only needed in math mode, the text mode versions of the curly braces are not changed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\{}{\ifmmode\lbrace\,\else\textbraceleft\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\}}{\ifmmode\rbracespace\else\textbraceright\fi}
\newcommand*{\rbracespace}{\,\rbrace}

\makeatletter
\let\saved@right\right
\renewcommand*{\right}{%
  \@ifnextchar\}{\,\saved@right\rbrace\@gobble}{\saved@right}%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
  \[ \{ a, b \} = \left\{ \frac{c}{d}, \frac{e}{f} \right\} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Further support for `\big` and friends

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\{}{\ifmmode\lbrace\,\else\textbraceleft\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\}}{\ifmmode\rbracespace\else\textbraceright\fi}
\newcommand*{\rbracespace}{\,\rbrace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\patch@for@rbrace}[1]{%
  % #1: command to be patched without backslash
  \expandafter\@patch@for@rbrace
  \csname saved@#1\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname #1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@patch@for@rbrace}[2]{%
  % #1: macro for original meaning
  % #2: command to be patched
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{%
    \let#1=#2%
    \renewcommand*{#2}{%
      \@ifnextchar\}{\,#1\rbrace\@gobble}{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}
\@for\x:=right,bigr,Bigr,biggr,Biggr,big,Big,bigg,Bigg\do{%
  \patch@for@rbrace\x
}
\renewcommand*{\bigl}{\mathopen\saved@big}
\renewcommand*{\Bigl}{\mathopen\saved@Big}
\renewcommand*{\biggl}{\mathopen\saved@bigg}
\renewcommand*{\Biggl}{\mathopen\saved@Bigg}
\renewcommand*{\saved@bigr}{\mathclose\saved@big}
\renewcommand*{\saved@Bigr}{\mathclose\saved@Big}
\renewcommand*{\saved@biggr}{\mathclose\saved@bigg}
\renewcommand*{\saved@Biggr}{\mathclose\saved@Bigg}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
  \[ \{ a, b \} = \left\{ \frac{c}{d}, \frac{e}{f} \right\} \]
  \[ \bigl\{ \mbox{big l/r} \bigr\} \]
  \[ \Bigl\{ \mbox{Big l/r} \Bigr\} \]
  \[ \biggl\{ \mbox{bigg l/r} \biggr\} \]
  \[ \Biggl\{ \mbox{Bigg l/r} \Biggr\} \]
  \[ \big\{ \mbox{big} \big\} \]
  \[ \Big\{ \mbox{Big} \Big\} \]
  \[ \bigg\{ \mbox{bigg} \bigg\} \]
  \[ \Bigg\{ \mbox{Bigg} \Bigg\} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what i was looking for. I'm glad you even mentioned the problem with `\right\}` because i am getting a similar problem using `\bigg\}` but `\bigg\{` seems to work fine.

Comment: @Peter: The extended answer also supports `\big` and friends.

Comment: For a resize-friendly command, you could also use the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from mathtools. If I say `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\setof}{\{\,}{\,\}}`, then I can later type `$\setof*{tall expression here}$` to have scaling braces. In my experience, the auto-scaling isn't perfect though...